# error al convertir FILE* to const char

Tags: c++

hola no entiendo por que tengo error (el que menciono en el titulo) en la siguiente linea

```
const char* filename = InFile;
```

el código es un poco extenso dejare el main

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    FILE* InFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    const char* filename = InFile;
    DWORD crc = GetFileCRC32(filename);

    DWORD wSize = GetFileSize(InFile, NULL);
    printf("crc32: %lu %lu", crc, wSize);

    fclose(InFile);
}
```

update,
como puedo pesarla un archivo a esta función para generar el crc32

```
DWORD GetFileCRC32(const char* c_szFileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(c_szFileName,                 // name of the file
                         GENERIC_READ,                  // desired access
                         FILE_SHARE_READ,           // share mode
                         NULL,                      // security attributes
                         OPEN_EXISTING,         // creation disposition
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,     // flags and attr
                         NULL);                     // template file

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        return 0;


    DWORD dwRetCRC32=GetHFILECRC32(hFile);

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwRetCRC32;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la firma de `GetFileCRC32`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El mensaje no puede ser más claro y explícito:

```
FILE* InFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
//    ^^^^^^ InFile es un puntero de tipo FILE

const char* filename = InFile;
//                     ^^^^^^ Como se convierte esto en un const char*???
```

No existe ninguna conversión (ni implícita ni explícita) que permita pasar de un `FILE*` a  `const char*`.

Si lo que quieres es obtener el nombre del archivo... ¿Por qué no lo recuperas de `argv[1]`?

```
const char* filename = argv[1];
```

En cualquier caso, ya que estás en C++ lo normal es que uses `ifstream` en vez de `FILE`...

Comment: hola, actualice el post; como podría entonces pesarla un archivo a esa función?

Comment: @crt Es que si lo vas a abrir con `CreateFile` tienes que eliminar el `fopen`... ¿Para qué quieres tener abierto el archivo dos veces?